# C Prog Newb: retrieve MYSQL query true/false value

Tags: mysql, c

Will try to make this simple - I can elaborate if needed:

Goal: trying to query MYSQL DB from C if a row or record exists using this command

```
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '123456789'
```

these are some of the test codes I've tried to get a proper return value from mysql.

```
    sprintf(exist, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '%s')", new_person.ID);
    printf("\n\nExists result: %s\n\n", (mysql_query(conn, exist))); // debug code - return NULL
    printf("\n\nExists = %s\n\n", exist); // debug code - output seems exactly what I want sent to database, I've tested with and without singles quotes ' '

    printf("\n\nMYSQL_QUERY: %d\n\n", mysql_query(conn, exist)); // debug code - testing return value - seems all successfull query return 1 - always return 1 regardless if id exists or not.

    printf("\n\nSQLSTATE: %d\n\n", mysql_stmt_sqlstate(exist));  // this does not return what's intended - looking for a value of 1 or 0 - returns 12935280

    test = mysql_stmt_sqlstate(exist); // debug code testing if correct value is assigned
```

The goal is to get a return of 1 or 0 from my db.  When I query mysql directly, i do get a true or false value as you can see below

```
mysql> select * FROM users;
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+------+
| id        | first_name | last_name | dob        | height | weight | BMI  |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+------+
| 123456789 | xxxx       | xxxxx     | xxxxxxxxxx |     xx |    xxx | xxxx |
| 254565    | Jessica    | Perez     | 05/03/2001 |     60 |    120 | 23.4 |
| 456132    | Tomas      | Aquina    | 02/01/1254 |     58 |    140 | 29.3 |
| 5245      | Herlinda   | Jones     | 12/01/1982 |     69 |    180 | 26.6 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+------------+--------+--------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 123456789);
+--------------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 123456789) |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                1 |
+--------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 6548);
+---------------------------------------------+
| EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 6548) |
+---------------------------------------------+
|                                           0 |
+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need the true/false value as a conditional for other parts of the code.
Sorry if this has been addressed or answered before.  I couldn't find it anywhere and I looked in MySQL reference at:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/c-api-function-reference.html

Thanks again!

For those who want to see the full code:

```
// 911Prep - software to track of household emergency needs
// Hans Yunge (C)2022

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

// header inclusions

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "911prep_header.h"

// function declaration
void create_person(Person* new_person);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char *query;
    char* exist;

    // calling creating Person function - printing out data

    Person new_person;
    Person_p ptr_person = &new_person;
    create_person(ptr_person);

    // BMI calculation
    new_person.BMI = new_person.weight / (new_person.height * new_person.height) * 703;

    // connect to mysql

    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    char* server = "localhost";
    char* user = "root";
    char* password = "password"; // set me first
    char* database = "911prep";

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (conn == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }

    // Connect to database
    
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
        user, password, NULL, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if (mysql_query(conn, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        mysql_close(conn);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nMySQL version is: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());

    // select database

    if (mysql_query(conn, "USE 911prep"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    }

    // check to see if row exists and update data to existing row

    query = (char*)malloc(200);
    exist = (char*)malloc(50);

    sprintf(exist, "SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '%s')", new_person.ID);
    printf("\n\nExists result: %s\n\n", (mysql_query(conn, exist)));
    printf("\n\nExists = %s\n\n", exist);

    printf("\n\nMYSQL_QUERY: %d\n\n", mysql_query(conn, exist)); // testing return value - seems all successfull query return 1

    int test = mysql_stmt_sqlstate(exist);  // this does not return what's intended - looking for a value of 1 or 0

        if (test == 1)
        {

            sprintf(query, "UPDATE users SET first_name ='%s', last_name = '%s', dob = '%s', height = %2.0f, weight = %3.0f, BMI = %2.1f  WHERE id=%s", new_person.firstName, new_person.lastName, new_person.birthDate, 
                new_person.height, new_person.weight, new_person.BMI, new_person.ID);

            if (mysql_query(conn, query))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                mysql_close(conn);
                exit(1);
            }
            free(query);
        }


        // insert new data into database

        if (test == 0)
        {
            sprintf(query, "INSERT INTO users (id, first_name, last_name, dob, height, weight, BMI) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %2.0f, %3.0f, %2.1f)", new_person.ID, new_person.firstName, new_person.lastName,
                new_person.birthDate, new_person.height, new_person.weight, new_person.BMI);

            if (mysql_query(conn, query))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                mysql_close(conn);
                exit(1);
            }
            free(query);
        }
        mysql_close(conn);


    //show data

//  printf("ID: %s\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nBirth Date: %s\nHeight: %2.0f\nWeight: %3.0f\nBMI: %2.1f\n\n", new_person.ID, new_person.firstName, new_person.lastName, new_person.birthDate, new_person.height, new_person.weight, new_person.BMI);

    return 0;


}
```

Comment: [`mysql-store-result()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/mysql-store-result.html) : `After invoking mysql_real_query() or mysql_query(), you must call mysql_store_result() or mysql_use_result() for every statement that successfully produces a result set (SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN, CHECK TABLE, and so forth). You must also call mysql_free_result() after you are done with the result set. `

Comment: balls...that sucks.  thanks!! lets see what happens... they make you work hard just to get a 1 or 0... lol

Comment: You should see OCI (Oracle's Call Interface). Anyway, if you're taking inputs from user in your software for querying database, consider using prepared statements to prevent SQL-Injections.

Comment: doesn't the sprintf create the prepared statement?... I thought that's what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my friend in the above comments leading me to pursue other unknown avenues and thanks to ZetCode @ https://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/
I'm on the right path... though have another issue.  I'm not understanding how to use the resulting value - when I use row[0] in a conditional I get an error.

```
    if (mysql_query(conn, exist) != 0)
    {
        finish_with_error(conn);

    }
    MYSQL_RES* result = mysql_store_result(conn);
    
    if (result == NULL) {

        finish_with_error(conn);

    }
    int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

    MYSQL_ROW row;

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
        {
            printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(conn);
```

The above is the basic format of what I'm trying to do which provided correct feedback, true and false from the query.

Comment: the correct output is printed with ```printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");```  but I can't seem to use the result as a conditional... the simple statement printf("%s", row[0]) gives me an error